# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources al generar un nuevo proyecto

Tags: android, android-studio

Actualmente cuando creo nuevos proyectos en Android Studio, me salen estos dos errores al querer correrlos; igual si no le he hecho ninguna modificación al proyecto:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
      > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
      > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

y

```
ParseError at [row,col]:[8,18]
Message: Las estructuras del documento XML deben empezar y finalizar en la misma entidad.
```

Guardo los proyectos en la carpeta por defecto: C:\Users\ACER\AndroidStudioProjects

---

Mi archivo AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.listadecompras">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ListaDeCompras">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

En mi AndroidManifest.xml está estructurado correctamente según verifico y probé el Buil -> Clean Project y Build -> Rebuild project pero no fue de ayuda. Todos los proyectos que creo intento correrlos apenas se generan pero igual saltan estos errores.

---

Mi archivo build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shoppinglist"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

El día de ayer me dejaba correr los programas sin problemas y de repente se me presentan estos errores

---

Desde ya agradezco sus ayudas

Answer (score 0):

Desinstalé Android Studio y lo volví a instalar y ya me deja correr los proyectos nuevos nuevamente. Capaz era cuestión de solo actualizarlo.